# Ralink RT3290 wireless 'device not ready' following upgrade Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: wireless, upgrade, ralink, 17.04

After upgrading two laptops to 17.04 (one Acer TravelMate and an older HP pavilion), the wifi on one of them (HP) speed working.

Output of lspci -v includes

```
09:00.1 Network controller: Ralink corp. RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe
Device name: 
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Ralink RT3290LE 802.11bgn 1x1 Wi-Fi and Bluetooth 4.0 Combo Adapter
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 16
Memory at b25100000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable- Count=1/32 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting 
Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 00-00-6f-42-bb-8f-8e-c4
Kernel drive in use: rt2800pci
Kernel modules: rt2800pci
```

I already tried restarting the network-manager service, and "ifconfig wlo1 down"/"up", but this yield an error "SIOCSIFFLAGS: Input/output error"..

Thanks for your help if you can suggest anything..

Comment: Is "speed working" good or bad? Also, check out https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos.

Comment: Thanks for commenting. I have installed a new driver now with a script (RT3290_u16). It renamed my wireless device to "eno1" and I can get it working, and speed is as normal. But in order for wifi to work, I need to install the driver every single time I start up the system, and in addition I need to do "ifconfig eno1 down", "ifconfig eno1 up", and  "service network-manager restart" - and then I need to connect to *hidden* network in order for the list of networks to become visible. The output of the script in the second answer on the link you posted: https://pastebin.com/RNqERspw